# Why this code returns the following error after compiling "invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')"?

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, variable-assignment, microcontroller

Given a 24bit string included in three 8bit registers, say:
array[0], array[1], array[2]
where the first bit of array[0] is the MSB and the last bit of array[2] is the LSB. My goal is to convert this string in an integer value.

For this purpose I have written the following code:

```
uint32_t bin2Int(uint8_t array[]) {
    uint8_t arr0[3];
    uint8_t mask = 0x80;
    uint8_t outputData[24];
    uint8_t s;
    uint8_t k = 23;
    uint32_t IntResult = 0;
    for (s=0; s<3; s++) {
      arr0[s] = *array[s];
      while (mask > 0) {
          outputData[k] = arr0[s] & mask;
          mask >>= 1;
          k--;
      }
      mask = 0x80;
    }
    for (s=0; s<24; s++) {
      if(outputData[s] != 0)
          IntResult += pow(2, s);
    }
    return IntResult;
}
```

This function is implemented in STM32CubeIde, when I build the project the compiler returns the following error: "invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')".
Before adding this code in my project I tested it in DevC ide and it works fine, but when I try it on STM32CubeIde it returns this error. What's wrong in my code? Thank you very much.

Comment: `array[s]` is an integer, why are you trying to dereference it with `*array[s]`?

Comment: From your description, the array bytes are organized as _big endian_. And, each byte has big endian bits. So, _no_ bit shifting/reversal within a byte is required. AFAICT, the code can be much simpler: `uint32_t bin2Int(uint8_t array[]) { uint32_t ret = 0; for (int s = 0;  s < 3;  ++s) { ret <<= 8; ret |= array[s]; } return ret; }`

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
arr0[s] = *array[s];
```

the right hand side expression has the pointer type `uint8_t *` while the left hand side expression has the type `uint8_t`.

It seems you mean

```
arr0[s] = array[s];
```

And the function should be declared at least like

```
uint32_t bin2Int( const uint8_t array[]);
```

And it is a bad idea to use the magic number `3`. You should to add one more parameter that will specify the number of elements in the passed array as for example

```
uint32_t bin2Int( const uint8_t array[], size_t n );
```

and use the variable `n` instead of the magic number `3`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this function is terrible.

As you use the STMCubeIDE, I assume it is for STM32 uC.

MSB is at index 0:

```
uint32_t bin24ToInt(const uint8_t *array)
{
    return ((uint32_t)array[0] << 16) | ((uint32_t)array[1] << 8) | array[2];
}
```

If bits are in the opposite order than usual:
(using ARM CMSIS intrinsic).

```
uint32_t bin24ToIntReverseBitOrder(const uint8_t *array)
{
    return (__RBIT(array[0]) >> 8) | (__RBIT(array[1]) >> 16) | (__RBIT(array[2]) >> 24);
}
```

Comment: Hi. I recognise that this code may be bad, but I am in a basic level and I am still learning. Thank you very much for your tip!